# I can't run a docker container of my reactjs app

Tags: docker, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to Docker and I tried to run a container of the `create-react-app` image so these are the steps that I have done:

1. `npx create-react-app frontend`
2. I created a `Dockerfile.dev` like below:

   ```
   FROM node:alpine
   WORKDIR '/app'
   COPY package.json .
   RUN npm install
   COPY . . 
   CMD ["npm" , "run" , "start"]
   ```
3. I used this command to build the image:

   ```
   docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .
   ```
4. When i run the container using the image id provided:

   ```
   docker run -p 3000:3000 my_docker_image_id
   ```

Nothing happens, [as seen in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdS1w.png).

But when I add the `-i` argument to my command everything works fine, [as seen in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjKPi.png):

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -i my_docker_image_id
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an issue with the version 3.4.1 of react-scripts,

So i added a docker-compose file and i specified this line who solve the problem and save my day :

```
stdin_open: true
```

So my docker-compose.yml file looks like this :

```
version : '3'
services:
    web:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        stdin_open: true    
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - .:/app
```

Comment: Glad to know Sir.

Comment: Aaa you made my day! thanks! `stdin_open: true` works

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` flag enables Interactive mode which connects the output to your terminal. Did you try accessing the site without the `-i` flag? It should have served your page, but just not display output to your console.

---

**UPDATE:**

So based on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688) you found, you'll also be able to use docker run with the `-it` flags. `-i` is explained above, but `-t` enables the TTY in a similar way to the `stdin_open: true` line in your `docker-compose.yml`

`docker -it run -p 3000:3000 my_docker_image_id`

---

Add the `-d` flag instead which enables Detached mode, and will allow Docker to run your container in the background. You can then run `docker logs {container_id}` to see the output of the server.

Here's a link in the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground

> When starting a Docker container, you must first decide if you want to
>   run the container in the background in a “detached” mode or in the
>   default foreground mode:
>
> -d=false: Detached mode: Run container in the background, print new container id

Comment: Thank you for the response but when i run the commande without -i and i try to access localhost:3000 i got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

And when i used the -d argument i run docker logs with my id container the same output is printed "Starting the development server..." and nothing happens , if i run docker ps after that i have no container running.

Comment: Try adding `EXPOSE 3000` to your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you again , it seem that you are the only one who help me :D , i try it an i have the same issue :(

Comment: Hello again Mr Joe , i found a solution and i think it is a problem in react-scripts@3.4.1 , so i added a docker-compose file and i added the flowing line who solved my problem :
stdin_open: true .

If you want to know more i provide you a link to the page that i found the soution in.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688.

Thank you again for your precisous help Sir.

Comment: Glad you were able to get working again. I did update my answer to also show what's needed to use the `docker run` version.

Comment: Thank you Mr Joe.